# hyperlink and image does't display

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I am using codeigniter with xampp and have two problem in my code

Hyperlink not work I try many method in different ways but not work

```
<a href="<?php  base_url();?> Login_v.php">Log in</a>
```

also  image doesn't display

```
<img src="images/login.jpg" width="150" height="40" />
```

I think the error in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /helloworld/

    # Disable rewrite for valid directory/files    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

    #map all request urls to a specific controller method
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/{controller}/{method}/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: `base_url()` is returning url not displaying it so use `echo base_url();`

Comment: You need to echo the base url: `<a href="<?= base_url();?>Login_v.php">Log in</a>`

Comment: It works   Thank you very much

Comment: But image doesn't display can you help me to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be

```
<img src="images/login.jpg" width="150" height="40" />
```

change to this

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/login.jpg" width="150" height="40" />
```

---

and loading file **should link to controller metho**d

```
<a href="<?php  base_url();?> Login_v.php">Log in</a> # Not works
```

**Solution**

```
<a href="<?php  base_url();?>controller_name/function_name">Log in</a>
```

inside controller

```
public function function_name()
{
    $this->load->view("login_v");
}
```

**In view**

Create/Move `Login_v.php` to `application/view`

Comment: Didnt wrk means which 1n??